# Regarding robots.txt disallow parameters URLs

Tags: html, wordpress, seo, robots.txt

I have pages that end in a search?=keyword and I want Google to prevent from crawling these pages. Example pages are below. I was wondering if I put a Disallow: /search in the robots.txt, will that work?

Example URL's:

```
http://www.website.com/search?=neymar
http://www.website.com/search?=ronaldo
http://www.website.com/search?=kobe
```

So basically, I do not want Google to crawl all the URL's that end in /search?=keyword. Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score -1):

It will work.

```
Disallow: /search?=*
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use the "Disallow: /" tag along with the URLs. This will work